# C#: the most efficient way to convert int[] into a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, optimization, int

I do know that this kind of questions have already been answered many times. Although I've found lots of possible answers, they still don't solve my problem, which is **to implement the fastest possible way to convert an integer array into a single string**. I have for example:

```
int[] Result = new int[] { 1753387599, 1353678530, 987001 }
```

I want it reversed, so I believe it's best to precede the further code with

```
Array.Reverse(Result);
```

Although I don’t iterate from the end, it’s equivalent to reversing, because I call elements from the end. So I have already done this. Just to let you know - if you can think of any other solution than mine, I suggest using this Array.Reverse, because the solution must be reversed.
I always care only about the last 9 digits of a number - so like modulo 1 000 000 000. Here is what I'd like to get:

```
987001|353678530|753387599
```

Separators just to have it clear now. I wrote my own function that is about 50% faster than using .ToString().
tempint - current element of the int array,
StrArray - a string array. It's not worth using StringBuilder or summing
strings, so at the end I simply join the elements of the AnswerArr to get the result.
IntBase - an array containing 1000 elements, numbers in strings from "000" to "999", indexed 0 to 999.

```
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
    //Some code here

    j = 3 * (limit - i);

    //Done always
    StrArray[j - 1] = IntBase[tempint % 1000];

    if (tempint > 999999) 
    {
        //Done in 99/100 cases
        StrArray[j - 2] = IntBase[tempint % 1000000 / 1000]; 
        StrArray[j - 3] = IntBase[tempint % 1000000000 / 1000000];
    }
    else
    {
        if (tempint > 999) 
        {
            //Done just once
            StrArray[j - 2] = IntBase[tempint % 1000 / 1000];
        }
    }
    }
    //Some code here

    return string.Join(null, StrArray);
```

There ale lots of calculations before this part and they're are done very fast. While everything goes in 714 ms, without summing integers, it's just 337 ms.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards,
Randolph

Comment: In the first paragraph. I'll bold it.

Comment: Please rename your variables to something that describes them. Your code is difficult to read.

Comment: Sorry, that was my first post here. OK, should be clear now.

Answer (score 4):

Faster? Most efficent? I am not sure, you should try it. But a simple way to convert

```
int[] Result = new int[] { 1753387599, 1353678530, 987001 };
var newstr = String.Join("|", Result.Reverse().Select(i => i % 1000000000));
```

Comment: shouldn't that be Result.Reverse().Select(i => (i % 1000000000).ToString()).ToArray() ?

Comment: Speed is nearly the same. So about 1600 ms. Anyway, I want to get a single string, not an array.

Comment: @L.B I was referring to devio's answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest L.B's answer for most cases. But if you're running for the top efficiency, here are my suggestions:

- You can iterate the array from the end, so there's no need to call `Reverse` of any kind
- `IntBase[tempint % 1000000 / 1000]` is the same as `IntBase[tempint % 1000]` because division has higher priority than modulus
- I bet the whole `IntBase` intermediate step is slowing you down tremendously

My suggestion would be something like this - much like L.B's code, but imperative and slightly optimized.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var ints; // Your int[]

// Initial step because of the delimiters.
sb.Append((ints[ints.Length - 1] % 1000000000).ToString());

// Starting with 2nd last element all the way to the first one.
for(var i = ints.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
{
    sb.Append("|");
    sb.Append((ints[i] % 1000000000).ToString());
}

var result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: instantiating `StringBuilder` with a proper fixed size, might make it a little bit faster; e.g., `new StringBuilder(20);`

Comment: Unfortunately anything with StringBuilder is too slow here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, I do need the top efficiency.

1. Sorry, I haven’t said it clearly, my fault. Although I don’t iterate from the end, it’s equivalent to reversing, because I call elements from the end. So I have already done this. I’ll correct this.
2. Of course it's not the same!

Comment: Maybe it slows down everything indeed, but your suggestion doesn't solve anything. And it's slower.
Unfortunately, your code doesn't work properly, since it doesn't consider that a number can be 1.000.000.001, for example. In such a case, it’ll show only “1”. So that’s wrong. And the second issue – even if that was OK, it took 1231 ms, in comparison with my 716 ms. As I said in the first message, it’s not efficient to use StringBuilder here.

Comment: 1) Reversing the array means either swapping the elements or producing a new array, in both cases that's an O(N) iteration. Then you are iterating _again_, so it is not equivalent in terms of performance.
2) I stand corrected, `%` is really in the same priority group as division.

Comment: As for the issue with 1000000001 showing only as 1, let me quote your original post: "I always care only about the last 9 digits of a number", so maybe you want to elaborate on the actual desired outcome.

Anyway you may be right that such numerical operations may be faster even than a StringBuilder. C# is not particularly good with strings in general (again in terms of performance).

Comment: 1) Anyway it works what I'm doing, so never mind. 2) I don't mean the priority, I mean it's wrong to say that IntBase[tempint % 1000000 / 1000] is the same as IntBase[tempint % 1000]. Let me give you an example, tempint  = 123456789. In the first case, the result is 456. In the second: 789. That's the difference. 3) Yes, I do care about these 9 digits. Aren't 00000000 digits? 4) So any idea for the improvement? :D

Comment: I was stupid with these % and /... Of course you're right. Silly me.